# Setting different UI theme for an angular app

Tags: angularjs

I have started working an app using angularjs which can have have different UI themes.

index.html

```
<html lang="en" data-ng-app="appConfigurator">
    <head>
        <title>The title</title>
    </head>
    <body data-ng-controller="appCtrl">
        <div data-ng-view></div>
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="libs/angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="libs/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/services/webservice.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/controllers/appCtrl.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/router.js"></script>
</html>
```

app.js - Here I initialize my module and also declare a global variable 'theme'.

```
var appConfigurator = angular.module("appConfigurator", ['ngRoute']);
var theme = "";
```

webservice.js - This service make Web service calls to the backend and gets the data as response.

```
appConfigurator.factory('webService', function($http) {
    return {
        callService : function(method, fileType, rowId, data, message, type) {

            return $http({
                method : method,
                url : url,
                data : "Message=" + message + "&XMLData=" + data + "&Type=" + type,
                headers : {
                    'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                }
            });

        }
    };

});
```

appCtrl.js - This is the main app controller. Here I am making a webservice call to get the data and then using this data I will have to make one more call to get the name of the "theme" I need to use. So basically two calls.

```
appConfigurator.controller("appCtrl", function($scope, webService) {

    $scope.succ = function(res) {
        //alert("success" + res.name);
    };

    $scope.err = function(res) {
        alert("error");
    }

    webService.callService('POST', 'data', 'ID', '', 'Message','XML').success($scope.succ).error($scope.err);
});
```

router.js - Based on the value of theme the route will route to the particular folder structure which will contain the theme specific HTML, CSS and JS files.

```
appConfigurator.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/Config', {
        templateUrl: 'themes/'+theme+'/views/a.tmpl.html',
        controller: ''
    }).otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/Config'
    });
}
]);
```

The obvious problem is that by the time routers sets the path for the tempelateUrl I don't have the name of the theme.

Solutions - 
1) One solution (this one works) is to get the theme name in the URL as a parameter but that cannot be done on the backend side. So there is no point of this solution.
2) Is there a way I can delay the routing process so that by the time angular tries to route I have the theme name.

The development is in very initial stage. Comments to change the approach will also be helpful. And yes Angularjs is all new to me and my peers.

Comment: What language are you using server-side?

Comment: @Andrew Church Well actual backend is Sieble system. We have our own middleware which is in Java and frontend can communicate with it via making calls to JSPs.

Comment: What I meant was, what are you hosting your single page application on? If you use a server-side page like a .php or .aspx, you could load the template when the request hits the server for that page, and just inject the var globally there before the response even goes back. Let me know what you're using and I can answer with a fiddle...

Comment: If I correctly understood your question then the answer is Tomcat.

Comment: No, do you have a JSP that's hosting your single-page app, or are you just using an html file to deliver your single-page angular app?

Comment: Aahh okay. It's an html file. You can see the index.html in my question. That's exactly how my current code looks.

Comment: Is the theme required in order for the app to work?

Comment: The idea is to get different UI themes based on combination of product and device (Here product can be any thing like a hard disk and device means ipad or desktop). So one combination can be that you are viewing a hard disk on an ipad. So the theme (in other words folder name) will tell me what UI files I should use. I hope I am not confusing you.

Answer (score -1):

```
appConfigurator.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {    
// set theme name

var theme = 'theme_name';

$routeProvider.when('/Config', {
    templateUrl: 'themes/'+theme+'/views/a.tmpl.html',
    controller: ''
}).otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/Config'
});
}
]);
```